# Pear upgrade over 7.5G?

Tags: php, pear

I am attempting to upgrade Pear, and it is currently asking for more than 7.5G of memory. I set memory limit in php.ini:

`memory_limit=7.5G`

and am still getting an memory error.

`$ pear upgrade`

`PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 7516192768 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in /usr/local/pear/share/pear/PEAR/Registry.php on line 417`

Any ideas on how to resolve, a little much isn't it?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards

Comment: In that case try setting `memory_limit = -1` to remove any memory limitations

Comment: Just out of interest, what version of PHP are you running? `php -v`